# Determine DDL statement in jdbc

Tags: oracle, jdbc

I'm writing a program that executes different sql statements(query, dml, ddl, dcl). How can I determine that executed statement(method `boolean Statement#execute(String s)`) was ddl or dcl. I know how to determine a query. Statement was a query when `execute()` method return `true`, when `statement#execute()` return value is false then it can be dml, ddl or dcl. So how to determine type of statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The presence of a result (`execute()` == true) does not necessarily indicate a query. e.g. in PostgreSQL a DELETE statement can also return a result (when using the `returning` clause).

To process all results or update counts of a statement, you need to implement a loop that follows the guidelines documented with the Javadocs of [`getMoreResults()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getMoreResults%28int%29):

> *There are no more results when the following is true:*
>
> // stmt is a Statement object 
>   ((stmt.getMoreResults(current) == false) && (stmt.getUpdateCount() == -1))

Comment: i've edited my question. I didn't tell earlier that i'm using oracle

Comment: @maks: The rule for getting all results and update counts still applies.

Comment: How execute() method can return multiple resultset if execute(String sql) can get only one query as a parameter?

Comment: Using the loop statement from the Javadocs ensures that you are processing everything that the statement returns. That's all I'm saying. It's the most portable way.